# Prove that if the roots of $10x^3-cx^2-54x-27$ are in HP then the roots of $27x^3+54x^2 +cx-10$ are in AP?

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics

I know we exchange $x$ by $\frac1x$ but how does that work?
AP-arithmetic progression
HP-harmonic progression

Comment: What are AP and HP?

Comment: What happens if you just exchange $x$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ above? The resulting equation will have reciprocal roots, and these will be in AP since their reciprocals, the roots of the original equation, were in HP.

Comment: Sorry but I just don't understand how the resulting equation will have reciprocal roots, I feel it just becomes and entirely new equation...?

Answer (score 1):

Roots of second in AP =>  one of this roots is -54/27/3 ( r-d + r + r+d = -54/27) => you can calculate unique value of c

Great overkill :)

Comment: Sorry but I just don't understand how the resulting equation will have reciprocal roots, I feel it just becomes and entirely new equation...?